# ASP.NET MVC: Best C# method of building a Json ActionResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Similar questions have been asked in the past, but they seem a little dated now. I'm trying to get the current general consensus on what's the best way to construct a JsonResult in ASP.NET MVC. The context of this question is to use the most current methods available from .NET 4/4.5 & MVC 4

Here's a few popular methods I've come across over the years:

```
var json1 = new { foo = 123, bar = "abc" };

var json2 = new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "foo", 123 }, { "bar", "abc" } };

dynamic json3;
json3.foo = 123;
json3.bar = "abc";
```

Please also the explain the pros/cons of your preferred method

Comment: Whatever works best for you and your team. All three methods produce the same result.

Comment: Use WebApi (http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead

Comment: -1 The question does not mention `ActionResult`.

Comment: @richard aside from the fact that a controller returns an ActionResult, how is it applicable to constructing JSON in C#?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally I use this one:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Foo = 123,
        Bar = "abc"
    };
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Pros:

- strong typing
- no magic strings
- refactor friendly
- unit test friendly
- the code is perfectly easily transposable to a new Web Api controller action call keeping the previous points true:

  ```
  public class ValuesController: ApiController
  {
      public MyViewModel Foo()
      {
          return new MyViewModel
          {
              Foo = 123,
              Bar = "abc"
          };
      }
  }
  ```

Cons: haven't encountered one yet.

Comment: string typing or strong typing ?

Comment: `strong typing` of course. `i` and `o` are next to each other on my (already broken) keyboard :-)

Comment: one con is that the first codeblock gives others access to your Json data as you just throw it onto the page. The Web Api not as this has CORS protection. So the Web API block is preferable if the data is sensitive.